# Implement forgot password functionality using Djoser

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, vuejs2, djoser

I am new to Django framework and now have a trouble with forgot password functionality. I have read the documentation about that functionality but have some not clear.
I need someone who can show me the steps on both frontend and backend in more detail.

```
reset() {
    var self = this;
    axios
        .post(this.$apiUrl + "password/reset/", {
            email: self.email
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to [documentation on this feature](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/stable/base_endpoints.html#reset-password).

Basically first you need to call the reset endpoint just as you did in question. Next the user should receive an email which will point them to the url given in `PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL` setting. On that url your frontend app should call the confirmation url on API (see docs).

Comment: can you please explain more . suppose I have `'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'reset/password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}'`  now how call `POST` to `auth/password/reset/confirm`

Comment: Djoser provides the API for your frontend, so your frontend needs to accept this url and then send POST request to the API with proper uid and token in POST body, as described in documentation. Then API will send back any results that the frontend part needs to interpret and show to user.

Comment: Ok so you mean frontend needs to accept this url : 'reset/password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}' and need to capture the `uid` and `token` from that url and send a `POST` request to `auth/password/reset/confirm`

How does frontend captures the url ? 

Suppose in my mail I have `http://127.0.0.1:8000/reset/password/reset/confirm/Mjk/538-954dccbc1b06171eff4d`  and when I click it directly redirects to the same url instead of `auth/password/reset/confirm`

Comment: I have the same question here : 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54322872/password-reset-implementation-with-djoser?noredirect=1#comment95465483_54322872

Comment: how do you specify the domain name of the URL? is it possible to do so by using `PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL`? This would be necessary when your front-end app (e.g. a react application is using another domain for the actual website that is separate from the djando api that uses Djoser)